# Overloading [] operator c++

Tags: c++, matrix

I am trying to overload the indexing operator for a c++ class but I am not able to do so. When I try to index my Matrix class, I get the following error:

error: cannot convert 'Matrix' to 'double*' in initialization

This error occurs on the 9th line of my main.cpp. Does it seem that the indexing does not seem to be recognized by the compiler?

Below is my code:

Matrix.h

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Matrix
{
    public:
        /** Default constructor */
        Matrix(unsigned int num_cols, unsigned int num_rows);
        /** Default destructor */
        virtual ~Matrix();

        /** Access num_cols
         * \return The current value of num_cols
         */
        unsigned int getCols() { return _num_cols; }

        /** Access num_rows
         * \return The current value of num_rows
         */
        unsigned int getRows() { return _num_rows; }

        double operator[](unsigned int index);

    protected:

    private:
        unsigned int _num_cols; //!< Member variable "num_cols"
        unsigned int _num_rows; //!< Member variable "num_rows"
        double ** _base;
};

#endif // MATRIX_H
```

Matrix.cpp

```
#include "Matrix.h"
Matrix::Matrix(unsigned int num_cols, unsigned int num_rows){
    _num_cols = num_cols;
    _num_rows = num_rows;

    if(_num_cols > 0) {
        _base = new double*[_num_cols];
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < _num_cols; i++) {
            _base[i] = arr;
            cout << _base[i] << endl;
        }
    }

}

double* Matrix::operator[](int index) {
    if (index >= _num_cols) {
        cout << "Array index out of bound, exiting";
        exit(0);
    }
    return _base[index];
}

Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    //dtor
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Matrix.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Matrix * m = new Matrix(1,2);
    double * d = m[1];
    delete m;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of the overloaded operator member function doesn't match the definition.

You defined the operator as:

```
double* Matrix::operator[](int index) {
```

But declared it as:

```
double operator[](unsigned int index);
```

The declaration should be:

```
double *operator[](int index);
```

Also, the problem with this line:

```
double * d = m[1];
```

Is that `m` is a pointer to a `Matrix` and the `[]` operator works on the class instance, not a pointer to it, so you need to dereference `m`:

```
double * d = (*m)[1];
```

Or you can define `m` as an instance of a `Matrix`:

```
Matrix m(1,2);
double * d = m[1];
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I made that edit, but I am still getting the same issue. I also edited main.cpp so line 9 reads: double * d = m[0]. Still no luck.

Comment: @KevinHoffman See my edit.  You need to dereference `m`.

Comment: @KevinHoffman Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.